# whats should i do if my data is remain not normally distributed every after log, log10

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, assumptions

I have a dataset about body vibration; the values are not normally distributed. For that, I tried the normal log, log10, but it remains not normally distributed.

What should I do?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw data?

Comment: Normality is not a universally good thing and is in fact not always achievable.  What you should do will depend on your goals and the likely consequences of trying various ways of achieving them.  In short, you would need to say much more to enable people to help you.

Comment: Why do you want to transform to normality?

Comment: What do you even intend to do with your data?

Comment: I'm trying to meet the assumption for the linear regression model

Comment: see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355879/making-left-skewed-distribution-normal-using-log-transformation/53356287#53356287) (which should be on CV) for some discussion of relevant issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, @Chicago2014 says:

> I'm trying to meet the assumption for the linear regression model

First, linear regression makes no assumptions about the distribution of the variables. It makes assumptions about the distribution of the *errors* which are represented by the residuals.

Second, if your residuals are not normally distributed, as seems likely, you should use a different method than OLS regression.  You could use quantile regression, a regression tree, some form of robust regression, or various other methods.